# Django 1.10 and httpd.conf

Tags: django, apache

According to Django 1.10 docs "Once you’ve got mod_wsgi installed and activated, edit your Apache server’s httpd.conf file", but httpd.conf is deprecated in Apache 2.4+. What is to edit?

Comment: Is it deprecated? Any relevant link please?

Comment: Whatever gave you that idea? Although if you're using a Debian-based distro, you should create a site-specific configuration in sites-available.

Comment: Can you give example of using sites-available?

Comment: Linux distributions generally provide documentation to explain it for you. For example for Debian https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.http-web-server.html and https://debian-administration.org/article/207/Maintaining_apache2_sites_and_modules_lists